# same symbol in different lib not redefine when linked to the same binary?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

#### Lib1.a:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
class Lib
{
public:
inline static const void Test()
{
printf("this is lib1\n");
};
void Lib1Test()
{
Lib::Test();
}
};
```

#### Lib2.a:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
class Lib
{
public:
inline static const int Test()
{
printf("this is lib2\n");
};
void Lib2Test()
{
Lib::Test(); // this will call the Test in Lib1,amazing!
}
};
```

lib1.a and lib2.a will be linked to test together.

What's the reason? Did not Lib::Test redefine?

Comment: is the effect independent of the order in which you pass your libs to the linker ?

Comment: above is a pseudo-code, the original project used cmake without any special order. the compiler is gcc4.7

Comment: i don't understand why the msvc and gcc not give the redefine warning when them linked to the same binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did not Lib::Test redefine

As dribeas already answered, your program is ill-formed (violates one-definition rule).

To understand why it does not fail to link, read about `COMDAT` sections [here](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/52).

Answer (score 2):

This is a violation of the One Definition Rule, which makes your program invalid but the implementation is not required to diagnose it.

Comment: *"but the compiler is not required to diagnose it."* You mean the linker or in precise terms an implementation isn't it? The two libraries are compiled separately and are just being linked together.Compilation of each library in itself is valid because there is no violation of ODR in that, it is an ODR while linking them together in the same binary.

Comment: The linker should not just emit a warning, it should not link at all and exit with an error. I think that the only reason that make this compiling is that  your functions are inline. I am really surprised that in your example Test() from lib1 is called.

Comment: @sbabbi You shouldn't be, and you wouldn't if you understood how comdat sections work: http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/52

Comment: @EmployedRussian nice link, but IIUC that would apply only if the compiler doesn't actually inline the function (i.e. taking the address of the function, recursion, impl-dependent, etc.) which doesn't seems the case (at least on this toy example).

Comment: @sbabbi The compiler is not obligated to inline anything, and the OP probably didn't build with optimization anyway. I expect the answer to change depending on `-O0` vs. `-O2` flags.

Comment: @sbabbi even if the compiler really inlined the calls, it might also generate the function. The standard requires that if the address of the inlined function is taken in different translation units the value will be the same. Some compilers do that by generating the inlined function as a weak symbol in all translation units. The reason that this is UB is that the implementation might generate code that does what you mean (really inlined) or that calls the wrong version of the function (not inlined, the linker will discard all but one) and the violation might be hard to detect for many reasons

Comment: @Als yes the proper term is *implementation*. Corrected in the answer.